# Reading input from user rather than stdin

Tags: c, pipe, stdin

Is there a way in c to get input from the user rather than stdin that may come from a pipe from another program?

I have a program that first prompts for a password using `fgets(pas, 256, stdin)` but the problem is would then read from stdin again which is commonly a pipe from another program so when I do `cat test | ./a.out` it would then read the password from the output of the previous program rather than prompting the user to enter it.

Comment: If your OS is UNIX or Linux you can read the input from `/dev/tty`, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html

Comment: If your OS is Windows, you can read the input using [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput).

Comment: thanks @Bodo, I have managed to do it by reading `FILE *tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");`. Good thing it also works with disabling the `ECHO` flag from `termios`. Apparently, it is also explained in the manual for `getpass()` probably should have read it first.